# Do military conflicts have tangible effects on climate change?

Tags: climate-change

Surely wars cause emission of a huge amount of CO2, but does that have a tangible effect in the short-term? For example, can someone claim that while currently there are 2 active wars (in Ukraine and in Gaza) they may have contributed to climate change? Or are the effects negligible to be felt in the short term?